# After CSS RotateX can't click on links or inputs

Tags: css, angularjs, z-index

Alright, I've made a plunker about the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/CUkOlK

At first I though zindex was messed up but after going through and looking at them they all seem fine, changed the input zindex to 9999 in firebug and still nothing, is it something that rotateX does or is it my JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem Is When You Set A Z-Index to -1 Anything On It Becomes Unselectable. I Changed It To 0 And Links Now Work!

{LINE 73 style.css}

```
/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */
    .front {
        z-index: 0;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Well that was easy... after banging my head against a wall for over a day.... i did not know that was the case.... appreciate it...

Comment: yea i was having that same issue awhile ago where i had a tab that slide out from underneath another div and all links were disabled. css can be weird sometimes